# Vim Hotkeys For Specific File

Tags: vim, html, hotkeys, keymap

Is it possible to set hotkey for specific file types in vim.

For example, if I am editing a .java file, I'd like vim to run javac .java when I press 5.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

~/.vimrc

```
autocmd FileType java map <F5> :! javac %<cr>
```

More info about [key mapping](http://howto.wikia.com/wiki/Howto_map_keys_in_vim) and [external commands](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/57727).

Comment: is it possible to remove the extension of the file? so that I can do like java %(remove .java)?

Comment: I doubt so, but you can make a shortcut to a script which will strip the extension and execute javac on the result.

Comment: @karmic: Use something like `autocmd FileType java map <F5> :exe '! javac ' . expand('%:r')<CR>`  See `:help expand()` for more information.

Answer (score 4):

*(I fail to understand the point of the dichotomy between SO and SU for such questions... Anyway:)*
Your question has already been answered, a few days later, on SO: [ftplugins + local mappings/abbreviations/commands are the way to go.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404515/gvim-and-multiple-programming-languages/1404570#1404570)

Regarding javac call, Just use %< to obtain the filename without the extension. A first correct mapping thus becomes:

```
:nnoremap <buffer> <f5> :!javac %<<cr>
```

But prefer instead to rely on the quickfix mode with:

```
:setlocal makeprg=javac\ $*
:nnoremap <buffer> <f5> :make %<<cr>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any direct experience writing anything like this from scratch with Vim, but here's what you'll want to look for examples to follow.

You probably want a filetype plugin (ftplugin) for .java files:

> A filetype plugin is like a global
>   plugin, except that it sets options
>   and defines mappings for the current
>   buffer only.  See
>   |add-filetype-plugin| for how this
>   type of plugin is used.

And use it with a mapleader+hotkey:

> To define a mapping which uses the
>   "mapleader" variable, the special
>   string "" can be used.  It is
>   replaced with the string value of
>   "mapleader". If "mapleader" is not set
>   or empty, a backslash is used instead.
>   ... To define a mapping which uses the
>   "mapleader" variable, the special
>   string "" can be used.  It is
>   replaced with the string value of
>   "mapleader". If "mapleader" is not set
>   or empty, a backslash is used instead.

You might have a look at the [Vim JDE scripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1213), or [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5054618.html) on configuring Vi(m) for Java development. [This page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Compile_Java_with_Sun_JDK_javac) has some information on using javac in Vim.