# How to set syntax specific settings in my VIMRC?

Tags: vim, vimrc, syntax, indentation

I work with several languages and markups in vim every day (ruby, python, javascript, CSS, HTML, etc), and would like to have different settings for each buffer when I fire up my editor. How can I detect which syntax is loaded in the current buffer?

Specifically, I really prefer python indent to be 4 spaces, while other languages are find with 2. I've envisioned something like this in my `.vimrc` file:

```
if syntax == 'python'
  set softtabstop=4
  set shiftwidth=4
else if syntax == 'html'
  " ...
endif
```

Anything like that in vim? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `FileType` autocommand event. See `:h autocmd.txt` for details.

```
au Filetype python source ~/.vim/scripts/python.vim
```

Comment: Why creating non standard directories ? -> ~/.vim/ftplugin !

Comment: Thanks - what I ended up doing is using your idea with some modification: `au FileType python set softtabstop=4 | set shiftwidth=4`

Answer (score 2):

ft-plugins are what you are looking for.

See the following answers:

- [Vim Hotkeys For Specific File](https://superuser.com/questions/47793/vim-hotkeys-for-specific-file/52894#52894)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404515/gvim-and-multiple-programming-languages/1404570#1404570